# http_client_requests_seconds_count metric giving random value after each refresh of /actuator/prometheus url

Tags: spring-boot, prometheus, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, prometheus-alertmanager

In my rest API, I am calling another API from another application. In order to capture total number of calls made from my API to that API, I am using  *http_client_requests_seconds_count* metric under /actuator/prometheus endpoint. I deploy my application and started making calls to my endpoint. Under http_client_requests_seconds_count I started seeing data like 1,2,3.... so on after each refresh.

But after making 8-9 calls, I am observing random count under *http_client_requests_seconds_count* like 9.. then 8 ... then 9... then 7... then 9 again etc...

Why this is behaving like this? As per my understanding, it should only be a incrementing data like 1..2..3........9..10... so on.

Comment: Yes, it should. Could be some incorrect load-balancing, caching, or something like that. Also, if it is self-developed service, it theoretically can provide custom `http_client_requests_seconds_count` metric (generally unlikely, but described behaviour is unlikely too).

Comment: Do you have a prometheus, scraping this endpoint? If yes, can you show graph generated by it's web ui, for mentioned metric?